# Collision Detection (doors)

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm making a Horror game in Unity3D, and at the moment I'm trying to create the scripts which will allow the player to open doors when he is near them. The problem is that the collisions between the doors collider and the player are not detected.

I've given the player a `RigidBody` component, while the doors don't have one. I've already written the script which let the player to open the doors by clicking the mouse, but I want to let him to do that only if he is near them. I tried to use:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
        isTouched = true;  //isTouched means that the door collider has been touched
    }
}
```

But it couldn't detect the collision and I couldn't explain why. So I tried with OnTriggerEnter, but the collision is still not detected. Does anyone have an idea of the reason for which they are not detected?

Comment: So if collisions are per-sé not working, i.e. the `OnCollisionEnter()` is never called, there's something wrong with your setup. Can you show us the colliders and the rigidbodies for the player and the door, and especially if they have `isKinematic` checked? For collisions, *both* objects have to have a collider and a non-kinematic rigidbody attached to them in order to trigger the call of these functions. Alternative to check "if a door is nearby": Convert the current mouse-position to a ray, shoot it into the world and see if it hits a door within a certain distance.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. In fact the problem was the isKinematic option, I didn't expect that was the problem..Now I'll use a ray as you said and I'll check the distance. Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: ensure both object hve collider and then expand the collider of your door